# How do i connect sqlite3 database to kivy?

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

i am new to Kivy, i am creating an app that retrieves information from the database. I tried connecting and anytime i run the code, it returns verification failed. below is the code.

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
import sqlite3
import kivy 
kivy.require('1.0.5') 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
#from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty 
Builder.load_file('screen.kv') 

class loginView(Widget): 
    status=ObjectProperty(None) 
    def validate(self,code):
        with sqlite3.connect("company.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            user = ("SELECT *FROM userinfo WHERE CODE = code")
            cursor.execute(user)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if code == result: 
                print (welcome )
                self.clear_widgets() 
            else: 
                self.status.text="Verification failed" 

class mainClass(App): 
    def build(self): 
        return loginView() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    mainClass().run()
```

____________________________screen.kv__________________________________________

```
<loginView>: 
    status:result 
    Label: 
            text:"Yousafe Systems" 
            pos:600,600 
            font_size:40



    Label: 
            text:"Enter code" 
            pos:450,400 



    TextInput: 
            multiline:False 
            pos:600,425 
            size:200,45 
            font_size:20 
            id:code 

    Button: 
            text:"Login" 
            size:100,50 
            pos:600,325 
            on_press:root.validate(code.text) 
    Label: 
            text:"" 
            pos:600,100 
            id:result
```

Update: I am sorry for the indentation errors. this is actually my first time of using SO. please find below the Link to the script folder. 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OnWFFtkT4gg_qg-f2uA-G2Nwn5SbRy80?usp=sharing

Comment: You know that once you leave the context manager block, `with sqlite3.connect("company.db") as db:` that the connection and the cursor are closed? That's the point of a context manager. This looks unrelated to kivy; you're trying to run a query on a closed connection because it's not indented to be inside that block.

Comment: Hold on, that's a substantial edit to the indentation, is that what the OP initially intended to post?

Comment: @roganjosh 
If it was not now it is, if that was the problem then it is already solved and it would be classified as a typographical error that is off-topic in SO so it should be closed, if you think about it you should give a closing vote. :)

Comment: Hello roganjosh?. Thanks for the response. What should i do in that case? How can i make it work?

Comment: @OlanrewajuOmoyele You could tell us how the table is structured, or better share your .db

Comment: @eyllanesc well I don't know if we're pushing a problem around. `code` is defined as an argument. Now I don't know whether it's an indentation issue in the scope of the context manager because the OP is unfamiliar with SO formatting or passing arguments to a parameterized query

Comment: @OlanrewajuOmoyele `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE CODE = ?", (code,))`

Comment: @roganjosh 
I already realized where the `code` is for that, delete my comment, on the other hand the error that I think is that `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples and if it is going to compare it with a string it will always be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is incorrect since you are looking in the database for the CODE that is equal to the "code", not the value of the variable code, on the other hand, comparing results with code will always be false since results is a list of tuples and when comparing it with a string it will never be true, if the code exists in the database then results will be a non-empty list, and we use that to check.

```
...
class loginView(Widget): 
    status=ObjectProperty(None) 
    def validate(self,code):
        with sqlite3.connect("company.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE CODE = ?", (code,))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if result: 
                print("welcome")
                self.clear_widgets() 
            else: 
                self.status.text="Verification failed" 

...
```

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc. It worked. What if i wanted it to print ("welcome" )+ the information corresponding to the code in the table?

Comment: @OlanrewajuOmoyele Use print("welcome", result[0]), If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the tour, that is the best way to thank. :)